# await is not waiting untill mongo write the collection

Tags: mongodb, async-await, promise

I have arrays with a few objects, which I want to store in `MongoDB`, here what I'm doing is, I created a `loop(map)`, inside this map before I start to write in DB I'm checking if the entry with `clause` is present if its present I'm ignoring it else I'm storing to `DB`, but it's not working as expected, it creating multiple duplicate entries in DB,

here below is the code I'm trying.

```js
Promise.all(
  payload.map(async (data) => {
    let existingConfigData = await this.userAssessmentConfigModel.findOne({
      userId: data.userId,
      assessmentId: data.assessmentId,
      assessmentType: data.assessmentType,
      stageId: data.stageId,
      courseId: data.courseId,
      workflowId: data.workflowId,
    });
    if (!existingConfigData) {
      const mongoData = new this.userAssessmentConfigModel(data);
      await mongoData.save();
    }
  })
);
```

and here is the mock data

```js
let payload = [
  {
    userId: 2,
    assessmentId: 1,
    assessmentType: "INTERVIEW",
    stageId: 1,
    courseId: 1,
    workflowId: 1,
    configData: {
      available: true,
    },
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    assessmentId: 1,
    assessmentType: "INTERVIEW",
    stageId: 1,
    courseId: 1,
    workflowId: 1,
    configData: {
      available: true,
    },
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    assessmentId: 1,
    assessmentType: "INTERVIEW",
    stageId: 1,
    courseId: 1,
    workflowId: 1,
    configData: {
      available: true,
    },
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    assessmentId: 1,
    assessmentType: "INTERVIEW",
    stageId: 1,
    courseId: 1,
    workflowId: 1,
    configData: {
      available: true,
    },
  },
];
```

any helps or suggestions are so helpful

Comment: All the calls of your `map` callback are running concurrently. You have a classical race condition. a) use database constraints b) use a sequential `for` loop c) de-duplicate the data on the client before inserting all at once